# Let $a$ be an odd integer. Prove by smallest counterexample that for any natural number $n$, $a^n$ is odd.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Here's what I've got so far, but once again, I'm stuck on continuing my simplification!

Proof.
Let $a$ be an odd integer.
Assume for the sake of contradiction that the statement is false for some natural number. Let C be the set of counterexamples, that is, $C = \{x \in N : 2|a^x\}$.
By assumption, $C$ is not empty. By the Well-Ordering Principle, $C$ has a smallest element, which we will call $x$. Note that x is not 0, because $a^0$ = 1, and 1 is odd, so $x \notin C$. Therefore, the claim holds for $x - 1$, that is, $a^{x-1} = 2k + 1$ for some integer $k$.

Scratch work:
$a^{x-1} = 2k + 1$
$a^x = a(2k + 1)$ 
$a^x = 2ak + a$

Where do I go from here? Am I taking the right path for simplifying? Obviously I want to end up with $a^x = 2k$.

Comment: HINT: $2ak$ is even, and $a$ is odd; what do you know about such a sum?

Comment: $2ak + a$ is odd.

Comment: Exactly. In other words, $a^x$ is odd, contradicting the choice of $x$.